# ember.js - unable to commit form data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm relatively new to ember.js and still having a painful time learning it. I am using the ember-rails gem, and Rails as a JSON API.

First I just wanted to build something that would display a list of records (in this case, emails) with the ability to add new ones. I have the UI setup and functioning, and ember is pulling the list of emails from the Rails API. I can click an email title and it takes me to the full email etc.

My problem is adding new records. I have a Compose Email form set up, but I still have not managed to add a new record, after several days of re-arranging code in routers and controllers. Every example I have found seems to suggest a different way of juggling transactions, createRecords, .get('store'), .get('content') and then committing the details through an action of some sort. None of them have worked for me. Here's what feels like the closest I've got:

**Store**

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend
    primaryKey: (type) -> '_id'

App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  revision: 11
  adapter: 'App.Adapter'
```

**Email model**

```
App.Email = DS.Model.extend 
  from: DS.attr('string')
  to: DS.attr('string')
  subject: DS.attr('string')
  body: DS.attr('string')
  created_at: DS.attr('string')
```

**Compose Route**

```
App.ComposeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
model: () ->
   transaction = this.get('store').transaction()
   email = transaction.createRecord(App.Email, {})
   return email

events: {
   save: (email) ->
     email.get('store').transaction()
}
```

**Compose Template** (trimmed of some HTML)

```
<label class="control-label" for="to">To</label>
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="to" id="to" placeholder="Your friend" required="true"}}
<label class="control-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="subject" id="subject" placeholder="What's it about?" required="true"}}
<label class="control-label" for="notes">Your message</label>
  {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="body" id="body" placeholder="Your message"}}
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" {{action save this}}>Send email</button>
```

**Rails emails_controller.rb**

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /emails.json
  def index
    render json: Email.all
  end

  # GET /emails/1.json
  def show
    email = Email.find(params[:id])
    render json: email
  end

  # POST /emails.json
  def create
    email = Email.new(params[:email])
    email.save
    render json: email, status: :created
  end
```

So with the above code I fill in the textboxes, click the submit button, and nothing seems to happen. However, if I go back to my Inbox page I can see the record I just added (woohoo!) but it's not persisted through Rails (hrmmm) - as soon as I refresh it's gone. Looking at the Rails logs, ember doesn't seem to be sending Rails anything.

I feel like I am going around in circles just trying different lines from various blog posts without really understanding the basic process. How should I be doing this? I've read through the Ember docs and while they explain the basic concepts, there are very few working examples using the RESTAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you save your record is still not correct.

You create a new transaction for your email, it is this transaction you want to commit, not the store's one.

```
App.ComposeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
model: () ->
   transaction = this.get('store').transaction()
   email = transaction.createRecord(App.Email, {})
   return email

events: {
   save: (email) ->
     // email.get('store').transaction() //This is only creating a new transaction
     // @get('store.defaultTransaction').commit() // this is committing the store's transaction
     email.get('transaction').commit()
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense and I finally have something being sent to Rails! I am getting another error though: `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key _id but you have no mapping for it.` We are using mongodb; I thought I had sorted this issue with `PrimaryKey: (type) -> '_id'` in the store.

Comment: Cool. My guess on that is your JSON is not formatted the way the `RESTAdapter` expects it. You may miss a root {_id: `} instead of {email: {_id: 1}}

Answer (score 2):

You never called `commit` anywhere in your code. Keep in mind that `store.transaction()` only gives you an instance of transaction, but you still have to `commit` (or `rollback` in `Route#deactivate`, if the user leaves that route). You might want to do your Route somewhat like this:

```
App.ComposeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
   transaction = this.get('store').transaction()
   transaction.createRecord(App.Email, {})

  deactivate: ->
    ## not super sure about modelFor in this case, but I think it should work
    record = @modelFor('email')
    ## There's more to check here, like is record 'inflight' and all
    ## but you get the idea.
    if ((record.get('isNew')) or (record.get('isDirty')))
      @get('store.defaultTransaction').rollback()

  events: {
   save: (email) ->
      @get('store.defaultTransaction').commit()
      ## or @get('store').commit()
  }
```

Comment: Oops - I did miss it in the above code but did try different ways of calling commit() before. I altered the Route to match your example and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined` for the @modelFor('email') line - my routes aren't nested, just a list of this.routes at the moment. As the UI doesn't nest in that way I thought that was the way to go?

Comment: Basically you need to find out whether the record you created in `model` is still dirty. You can have a flag exposed as computed property, or you can try to access the record to check. So instead of `modelFor`, try `record = @get('controller.content')`.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I changed it as you suggested and that gets rid of the error, but there's still nothing getting sent to Rails. The new email appears in the inbox view but is gone after a refresh.